# How to sort SQL Wide Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with more than 1024 columns. We are using Wide Table to handle this scenario. Sorting by the clustered index(PK) works without any issue but when it is sorted by any other columns then i get the following exception.

```
Select PK,c1,c2,c3....,c2400 from table order by c1
```

> Msg 8618, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a
>   worktable is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum
>   allowable of 8060 bytes. A typical reason why a worktable is required
>   is a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause in the query. If the query has a
>   GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause, consider reducing the number and/or size
>   of the fields in the clause. Consider using prefix (LEFT()) or hash
>   (CHECKSUM()) of fields for grouping or prefix for ordering. Note
>   however that this will change the behavior of the query.

Let me know a possible solution to sort the wide table.

Comment: How many columns are you sorting by vs how many columns do you need to sort by?

Comment: Create calculated field which is a concatenation of all fields to be sorted and sort by this calculated field.

Comment: Request you to put your actual query and problem you are facing so it will be easy to find out the solution. Also request you to provide table structure.

Comment: Try to use `RTRIM(yourField)`

Comment: @JamesAMohler : Sort can happen to any columns or to any number of columns.

Comment: @SurajKumar: Please check on the below link for structure, 
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/78e9cc8c-b30b-43c0-b62e-6c06e1bfcff9/how-to-sort-sql-wide-table?forum=transactsql#78e9cc8c-b30b-43c0-b62e-6c06e1bfcff9)